# Graph bounded by vertical line, and rotated about a horizontal line, using a cylindrical method

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$2y^2$, $x=2$, $y>=0$, and about $y=2$

I've tried y as radius and $(2-2y^2)$ as width with b = 1 and a = 0.

Because this is how I solved a similar question for rotation about the x-axis with vertical line boundary.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong with this question?

Comment: First, graph the region being rotated and the axis of rotation.  Draw the shell positioned at $y=y_0$.  What is its radius?

Comment: y or (2 - y). I think it ought to be y imo.

Comment: The radius is the distance from the center of the shell to the edge.  If the center is at $y=2$ and the edge is at $y=y_0$, what is the distance between those $y$-values?